# push notifications for multiplayer games

Tags: android

I have a general multiplier question. When we look at games such as clash of clans or any mutliplayer game that involves many players at the same time. Are all the information exchanges to determine the game movements/changes based on push notifications, or is it polling or is P2P/mesh connection?

I just always thought of push notifications as for important messages and I am not sure if using it realtime is valid

Comment: I think you could use XMPP for that, because it maintains a connected state and can let you know immediately the user gets disconnected. Push notifications don't seem that reliable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the Parse service.

https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

There is an API to send notifications and track all phones

On a task completition you can call the api (**with the gameserver**) to send notification to your phone.
No need the app to be open.